# How to report a crash bug with nothing on screen

Tags: bug-reporting, multi-touch, touchscreen

I would like to report an installation bug, but I can't launch ubuntu-bug :

On my tablet (LDLC Janus, an Intel based tablet without OS installed by default), I have a problem when I install Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10. Once the installation is finished, when I reboot, there is ABSOLUTELY nothing on screen, but Ubuntu boot correctly anyway : I choosed auto-login mode and I can hear the login sound. Even if I Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2... there is nothing. But the livecd works fine (even touch screen even if without multi touch). I tried to install 10.10 it works, but as soon as I upgrade the same problem occure. i installed Fedora 15 and then Fedora 16 (because of other problems) and no problems with them.

I would like to report this bug on launchpad but I don't know how to do to give devs logs files and other useful files which could help debug.

Thanks a lot for your answer, I would really prefer using my tablet with Ubuntu (I miss U1, USC, Unity)

---

Bug reported here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-friendly/+bug/889459 Do you know if this is the good place, and what is needed more ?

Comment: Did you tick the box "Install proprietary software and codecs" during the installation? If yes, I'd recommend you to try it again without ticking that box. It might have installed the wrong graphic driver.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 have problems with your display.  Now that you can boot with live CD, I suggest that once your tablet is up with the live CD, you mount your system and chroot into it:

```
$ umount /dev/sda1 # suppose it's your hard disk with Ubuntu on it, 
                   # and the mount point is / (root)
$ mkdir /mnt/system
$ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/system  # if you have other mount points such as /usr, /bin
                               # you have to mount them under /mnt/system/usr, etc
$ chroot /mnt/system
```

From here on, it's like you are on the shell of your tablet itself, instead of on the live CD.  You can install openssh on your tablet then:

```
$ apt-get install ssh
```

and find out the IP address of your tablet:

```
$ /sbin/ip -f inet addr
```

then, reboot the tablet from its own hard disk, from another computer in the same network, you can use ssh to log into your tablet once it is up, and check the error logs and `dmesg`, etc., as the IP address should be the same.

However, if the IP address do change between you shutting down your tablet and restarting it, you need to set a static IP address to your tablet.  Please see [this page](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/319) on how to do it, and make sure you do it after you `chroot` into your tablet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Do you know then under witch package I have to report the bug on launchpad ?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Ubuntu on tablet devices, so I am not sure which package is responsible for the touch screen. My guess would be those with "xinput" and "touch" in their names.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same tablet. Here's what I've done:

- If you dont have grub press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> at booting.
- Change the grub seetings to always show and to 640x480.
- Then `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-video-intel` in ubuntu recovery root console
- I can't get the keyboard to work, and that would be the last thing (it's a bluetooth keyboard)

I'm using Edubuntu 12.10